# Bash script to create multiple screens that runs python script

Tags: python, linux, gnu-screen

I have 20 python scripts that I want to run in 20 different screen sessions.

I have created the following bash file (test.sh):

```
screen -dmS test1 python script1.py
screen -dmS test2 python script2.py
screen -dmS test3 python script2.py
```

The problem is that it is not creating the screen session and not running anything. In addition, if someone actually provides a solution, I do not want the screen to terminate after executing the screen.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: You realize that the screens are being detached and you will not see any output. Try `screen -r` to see detached screens.

Comment: Actually, you should use `screen -ls` to see the detached screens.